# How to troubleshoot remote PowerShell with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell ISE on my local client to access my SharePoint Farm. I am getting the error: "Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again."

I have given my account admin permissions in the:
WSS_Admin_WPG on the SP Servers
SharePoint_Shell_Access role on database
Security_Admin role on the SQL instance
db_owner role on the database (in fact I gave myself db_owner and SP_Data_Access on all of them at one point)
I am also local admin on all the SharePoint servers

What am I missing?

Comment: I was talking to one of my former colleagues who has attempted a Windows server to SQL server from a client PC and he said it involves one more step. The server PC machine name also needs permissions on the SQL server machine as well as the necessary databases. So, the double hop needs both the user account and all computers involved in the permissions exchange.

Answer (score 1):

When running PowerShell ISE, you need to Add-PSSnapin to Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

```
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
     Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
```

Run this script and try again.

And as always, you have to be on the server when running scripts!

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned I can run the Add-PSSnapin successfully.

Comment: @Justin Great! If that helped you - you can accept this answer which will help others with the same problem. :)

Comment: I wish that was all. At that point when I try to "Get-" anything from the farm, I get the error I posted.

Comment: @Justin You have to be on the server!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I am trying to follow the plethora of instructions on how to remote to a SharePoint server from a client workstation. When I either start a new remote session or enter a ps session with my credentials, I can access the server and see the commands are available to me but I can't access the farm. Are you saying even though I am remotely connected, I can't run scripts?

Comment: Benny is correct, you need to run the script on the server where SharePoint is installed.

Comment: So what is the point of setting up enabling remote shell access, giving permissions to a user in SQL, and establishing a remote session? Can you give me an example script or cmdlt of what you would run from a client remotely connected to a SharePoint server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the server object model from your client. You need to use the client object model. You can only load the snap-in on the server itself.

Download the client SDK from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35585

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start >> Type “PowerShell ISE”.
Right, Click and Open PowerShell ISE with “Run as Administrator” if you have UAC enabled.
Now, You can start writing your PowerShell script or copy-paste the script and then click on the “Run Script” button from the toolbar.

Hope You Find This Useful,
Peter